# Calling specific dictionary values from a dictionary with multiple values per key, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have a df that contains columns for vendor_name, street_address, city, state, country, zip_code. I've converted this to a dictionary:

vend_dict = vendor.to_dict

I have another df that has a column for vendor_name, but is missing all address info. I would like to map the dictionary against the new dataframe (df2) to create additional columns populating street, city, state, etc.

How do I map a dictionary to populate specific values into specific columns?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the data frames instead of your current method.

For example, if you had data like:

```
df1:

vendor_name | street_address | city | state | country | zip_code
------------+----------------+------+-------+---------+---------
vendor a    | ...            | ...  | ...   | ...     | ...
vendor b    | ...            | ...  | ...   | ...     | ...
vendor c    | ...            | ...  | ...   | ...     | ...

df2:

owner name | vendor name
-----------+------------
Bob        | vendor a
Sam        | vendor c
```

Then you can do the following:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on="vendor_name", how="left")
```

This will produce:

```
df:

owner_name | vendor_name | street_address | city | state | country | zip_code
-----------+-------------+----------------+------+-------+---------+---------
Bob        | vendor a    | ...            | ...  | ...   | ...     | ...
Sam        | vendor c    | ...            | ...  | ...   | ...     | ...
```